Kids show involving a guy named "Nathan"
There was this show which I used to watch as a kid (about 10-15 years back). I think it was on POGO channel. It involved some teenagers dancing, singing etc to entertain kids. I remember only one guy's name - Nathan. There was about 3 others, one was a blonde girl.
I remember one episode in which the girl tells like - "Today I am going to have a fruity breakfast" and cuts some fruits. There was also an exercise demonstration which shows basic exercises like stretching. One other thing I remember is that - they all wearing pink/red dresses having heart shapes on it and dancing. Anyone able to identify?

Sounds like Hi-5, which started in 1999. It aired on POGO TV in India.

Hi-5, an Australian children's television program, was first shown on the Nine Network in 1999 and is based on the children's music group Hi-5. Hi-5 is a children's pop music group much like peer children's entertainers The Wiggles. Hi-5 has been shown in approximately 80 countries.

One of them was called Nathan, and here's a clip on Youtube where cast member Kathleen cuts up some fruits for a 'fruity' breakfast snack. There were also some stretching exercises. Here's the gang:

